# Encrypt and Decrypt with PKCS7 in iOS

Tags: ios, openssl

I have a certificate file crt and private key pfx file.

I need to encrypt the text to send to server. In server side, they are using the PKCS7 encrypt and decrypt method.

How can be done in iOS side ?

I added openssl from https://github.com/st3fan/ios-openssl

I found `PKCS7_encrypt` and `PKCS7_decrypt` in openssl header.

However , I don't know how to use it.

If somebody already know how to encrypt and decrypt with PKCS7 on iOS , guide me , please.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [reading the manual](http://bit.ly/QVtXhe)?

Comment: yes, I don't know , how to load STACK_OF(X509) for PKCS7_encrypt

Comment: Well, the [crypto (3) page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/crypto.html) links to the [x509 page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/x509.html), which links to [d2i_X509](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/d2i_X509.html), which is one way to read certificates into OpenSSL...